# 3proxy, CentOS 7

Tags: centos, proxy

Имею два ip v4 (VPS). Система CentOS 7. Установил и настроил 3proxy. С одним ip адресом (тот, что был выдан при покупке сервера) - прокси работают. Никак не могу настроить конфигурацию для работы с вторым ip. Поправьте меня, буду рад советам. Сам конфиг:

```
daemon
nserver 1.1.1.1
nserver 1.0.0.1

nscache 65536
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
users usertest:CL:passtest "test:CR:$1$qwer$CHFTUFGqkjue9HyhcMHEe1"
archiver gz /bin/gzip %F
rotate 20

auth iponly

external 000.000.00.01
internal 000.000.00.01

auth none

dnspr

auth strong
deny * * 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.1
allow * * * 80-88,8080-8088 HTTP
allow * * * 443,8443 HTTPS

auth none
pop3p

tcppm 25 mail.my.provider 25

auth strong
flush
allow usertest
maxconn 200
socks -p1080
proxy -p3128 -i000.000.00.01 -e000.000.00.01-a
proxy -p3128 -i000.000.00.02 -e000.000.00.02 -a
```

Answer (score 0):

При попытке загрузить страницу с "нерабочим" прокси я начал подозревать, что в интерфейс(eth0) не добавлен ip, потому что браузер выдавал таймаут(60 сек), а не ошибку: прокси сервер не отвечает. Я сделал `ifconfig -a` и действительно, только 1 ip. Я добавил на этот интерфейс(eth0) второй прокси `ifconfig eth0:1 000.000.00.02 up`. После команда `systemctl restart 3proxy` и всё заработало. Надеюсь что это может кому-нибудь помочь.